# What's this handwritten character?

Tags: handwriting

I'm having trouble figuring out what characters these are:

[image]

I guess the two on the right are "まだ", but what's the one on the left?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming there is not anything preceding these letters that would alter its meaning, that would appear to say:

> `好きだ`
>
> I (Like / Love) (You / It)

"き" is often handwritten without the bowed bottom.

[image]

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you so much! These characters were on a note by themselves, so I think this is it.

Comment: No problems. I added a bit more detail if you were interested.